# Inherit Color from Parent and Perform Color Shading in CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way in CSS to take the active color defined by a CSS class and either darken or lighten the color to be used in another CSS class?

**DEVELOPMENT SCENARIO:**
We have a dialog that uses a CSS style that defines its color as a shade of gray.  In the dailog, we have buttons that use 2 different CSS styles that simulate the button up and a button down states.

Is it possible to have the CSS style(s) of the buttons to use the dialog color but have it darkened or lightened for the button appearance.  The button face should be lighter than the main dialog color, and use lighter and darker colors for the borders which give the appearnce of a 3D button frame.

**GOAL:**
If we change the color of the dialog, the buttons would also change without having to make any code changes to the 2 CSS styles that are used to render the up and down states for a button.

I am guessing that there is a way to do this in JavaScript, but is there a way in CSS to perform this action?

Comment: There is no pure css way to change colors, because does not have things like equations, functions, or variables. It will be interesting to see if justin has an opacity way though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a white or black background with an [opacity](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp) appropriate for the amount you want it lightened. Opacity is a bit challenging to use (relative to other more common CSS properties) since it requires browser-specific hacks. According to [this blog post](http://davidwalsh.name/css-opacity), the following (hacky) CSS will work across browsers to support 50% opacity :

```
.show-50 { -khtml-opacity:.50; -moz-opacity:.50; -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)"; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50; zoom:1; }
```

BTW, I answered [another stackoverflow question related to Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665313/jquery-globalcss-ie-opacity/1682256), and it contains some jQuery code samples which can be used to apply opacity in a browser-neutral way.  You can use that instead if the CSS above makes you gag. :-)  Note that I added the "zoom:1" above to ensure the element has "layout" which is an IE-specific prerequisite for applying opacity-- this issue is also described in this thread linked above.

You can also use a PNG image which is white but has the transparency value you prefer. This requires the usual PNG-fix solution in IE6.

Here's a code sample illustrating what's possible (and some limitations):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .button { background-color:green; height:30px; width:100px; border: solid 1px red; color:#FFF; margin:20px; text-align:center;  }
        .buttonText { height:30px; width:100px;  color:#FFF; margin:20px; text-align:center;  }
        .show-50 { -khtml-opacity:.50; -moz-opacity:.50; -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)"; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:.50; zoom:1; } 
        .lighter { background-color:#CCCCCC; height:100%; width:100%; }
        .darker { background-color:#000000; height:100%; width:100%;}
        .whitetext {color:#fff; height:100%; width:100%; padding-top:6px;}
        .moveText {margin-top:-52px; color:#fff; padding-top:6px; z-index: 10; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="button"></div>
 <div class="buttonText moveText">Regular button</div>
 <div class="button"><div class="show-50 lighter"></div></div>
 <div class="buttonText moveText">Lighter button</div>
 <div class="button"><div class="show-50 darker"></div></div>
 <div class="buttonText moveText">Darker button</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On IE8, the text looks perfect (aka white). On FF and Safari, the text is unfortunately darkened.  The hack above where I put the text into a different DIV tricked IE into displaying white text over the different-colored backgrounds, but the same trick didn't work on FF and Safari.  I suspect you could get creative and find ways to improve upon this so the text stays the same color in all browsers.  A real impletation would probably also want to use absolute positioning rather than my negative top-margin hack.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)? It supports variables among many other things:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;
@light-blue: @nice-blue + #111;

#header { color: @light-blue; }
```

LESS does require preprocessing during deployment, however - so if you need to do the above at runtime, this may not be an option (but then JavaScript would be the only viable option, anyway).

Comment: Wow, LESS looks really cool. I think I'll take a stab at porting it to PHP this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a dynamic css file with PHP and have a function to calculate the brightness of a color automatically.  You can have a setup that changes a color that is defined in many different places by just changing 1 field.  Here is an example:

```
<?php
//adjust brightness by taking a value between -255 and 255
function brightness($color, $brightness){
   if(!$color) return false;
   $c = trim($color);
   $c = str_replace('#','', $c);
   $l = strlen($c) == 3 ? 1 : (strlen($c) == 6 ? 2 : false);

   if($l){
     $rgb[0] = hexdec(substr($c, 0,1*$l)) + $brightness;
     $rgb[1] = hexdec(substr($c, 1*$l,1*$l)) + $brightness;
     $rgb[2] = hexdec(substr($c, 2*$l,1*$l)) + $brightness;



    }else{
      return false;
    }

    $out = '#';
    for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
      $rgb[$i] = dechex(($rgb[$i] <= 0)?0:(($rgb[$i] >= 255)?255:$rgb[$i]));

    for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
      $out .= ((strlen($rgb[$i]) < 2)?'0':'').$rgb[$i];

   return $out;
}

// Color Setup
$myColor = "#3399CC";
$myLighterColor = brightness($myColor, "50");
$myDarkerColor = brightness($myColor, "-50");


// Include this if using a seperate style sheet
// header("Content-Type: text/css");
?>
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color:<?=$myLighterColor;?>;
  }

  #div1 {
    background-color:<?=$myColor;?>;
    border: 1px solid <?=$myDarkerColor?>;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS answer is no you can't. You could however use SASS http://sass-lang.com which also require pre processing though.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use a background image. One black (it's enough with a one pixel image) with opacity set to twenty or something, and one white also set to around 20.